# Create a list of one object type from a list of another using Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

If I have classes of Type A and B:

```
public class A
{
    public int TotalCount;
    public string Title;
}

public class B
{
    public int Count;
    public string Title;
}
```

I have a list of instances A instances,  what is the most efficient way to create and populate a List of type B using Linq?

Comment: Your question is unclear... what's the relation between A and B ?

Comment: Essentially they represent the same thing.  In my actual case, A is a class generated by Linq to Sql when I created a Linq to Sql class and added a table to it.  Because class A has Linq and Linq to Sql dependancies, I do not want to expose it to my applications, so I create class B, that has no dependancies.  So I need to populate a list of class B instances from a list of class A instances.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
List<B> listB = listA.Select(a => new B()
   {
        Count = a.TotalCount,
        Title = a.Title
   }).ToList();
```

Does the same as eduncan's solution with different syntax. Take your pick..

Comment: Is there a way to filter values out of listA as well so that listB doesn't need to have every item there is in listA?

Comment: @user20358 Yes, LINQ has a Where function. Before the ToList() you could call something like this: .Where(w=> w.TotalCount > 5) then call .ToList();

Answer (score 13):

```
var list = 
  from a in TableA
  select new B {
    Count = a.TotalCount,
    Title = a.Title
  };
```

You new up an instance of B in your select clause, and assign the properties using the inline property assignment feature in C# 3.0.

The advantages of mapping it inline comes from deferred execution of your Linq statement.  Linq will map the modified statement, and execute it from your IQueryable.  For example:

```
public class ClassA 
{
  public int TotalCount;    
  public string Title;
}

public class ClassB
{
  public int Count;
  public string Title;
}

public IQueryable<ClassB> FetchAllOfClassB()
{
  var list = 
    from a in TableOfClassA
    select new ClassB {
      Count = a.TotalCount,
      Title = a.Title
    };

  return list.AsQueryable();
}
```

Technically, the `AsQueryable()` is a bit redundant.  Sometimes I use it to make it a point, others say it is absolutely required.  None the less, the list object itself is IQueryable of ClassB.

Then you can call `FetchAllOfClassB()` further up the chain, and use IQuerable.  It's pretty slick, and efficient.

Comment: Just about to write something like this, but you've got it covered! +1

Comment: THanks guys.  Upped your comments as well.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, off the top of my head (so there will probably be errors!):

`List< B > = from a in listOfA select new B(a.count, a.title);`

might do the trick.